# Getting back the string values from previously label encoded values in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, encoding, label, unsupervised-learning

I wanted to predict some string values using unsupervised learning. I converted a categorical column into numerical by using label encoding and predicted the values. Now I want to know the string values of the predicted numerical values(label encoded values)

```
input: predictedvalues = [1,2,4]

output: 1-car
        2-bike
        4-cars
```

Comment: please provide more info about your input and the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't mentioned the library used for label encoding, I'll presume you are using `sklearn`. If so, then you can use the [`inverse_transform()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.inverse_transform) function.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(['car', 'bike', 'cars'])

print(le.classes_)

le.transform(['car', 'bike', 'cars'])
```

Output:
`array([1, 0, 2])`

Now let's invert the output

```
le.inverse_transform([1, 0, 2])
```

Output:
`array(['car', 'bike', 'cars'], dtype='<U4')`

Here's a link to a live executable [Deepnote notebook](https://deepnote.com/project/eba76d78-2de4-4205-8ccd-88725f8f240d) if you wish to test the code above.